# Erro ao consumir Web Service ASMX

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service, windows-phone, asmx

O erro é esse:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

Tenho dois Projetos:

1º WebService, pra rodar o Web Service

`WebService.asmx:`

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public Boolean Autenticar(string usuario, string senha)
        {
            if (usuario == "admin" && senha == "admin")
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

2º WindowsPhone, uso emulador para rodar.

Foi adicionado a Referencia com o nome de "DadosService" e link "http:/ /localhost:27128/WebService.asmx" (sem espaços)

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DadosService.WebServiceSoapClient service = new DadosService.WebServiceSoapClient();
            service.AutenticarCompleted += service_AutenticarCompleted;
            service.AutenticarAsync("admin", "admin");
        }

        public void service_AutenticarCompleted(object sender, DadosService.AutenticarCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Certo");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Errado");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @TiagoSilva publiquei ele no IIS como "http://192.168.2.102:8080/Service/" e mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: @TiagoSilva Não consigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro a partir desse [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robert_mcmurray/connecting-the-windows-phone-8-emulator-to-web-api-applications-on-a-local-computer).

Desabilitei o firewall e tudo deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DadosSevice.WebServiceSoapClient service = new DadosSevice.WebServiceSoapClient();
        bool validou = service.Autenticar ("admin", "admin");

        //test the return from webservice
        if (validou)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Validou");
        }
    }
```